# AMP validation error: The attribute 'controls' may not appear in tag 'amp-base-carousel'

Tags: amp-html

I am using https://search.google.com/test/amp to validate my web site but it's failed with error message: `The attribute 'controls' may not appear in tag 'amp-base-carousel'.` while I checked the 'amp-base-carousel' guideline https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-base-carousel/#controls, the attribute 'controls' is valid.

Please help me to resolve this. Thank you so much.

Here is my code for `amp-base-carousel`

```
<amp-inline-gallery layout="container">
<amp-base-carousel class="amamp-product-list" 
layout="responsive" 
width="313" height="240" snap-align="center" 
loop="true" 
auto-advance="true" 
auto-advance-interval="5000" 
visible-count="1" 
lightbox 
controls="never">
<div class="amamp-product-item">
...
...
...
```

Comment: assuming that you are loading all relevant libs (which is a poor approach as assumptions make an ass of you and me - assum) this looks like a bug. Suggest you open an issue on https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues